# Получить русские слова

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python. Необходимо получить массив русских слов (не обязательно актуальных и всех). Видел вот это:
https://github.com/danakt/russian-words
Но моих знаний программирования недостаточно, чтобы как-то с этим связать.

Comment: Опишите, чего вы хотите получить

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для этого нам нужно будет установить библиотеку **requests** через *pip*. Команда:

```
pip install requests
```

Если у вас нету *pip*, скачайте его следуя инструкции на официальном сайте *PyPI*.

А теперь дело за кодом. Так как у нас ссылка ведет на *Raw* версию файла на *GitHub*, то с помощью запроса мы попробуем получить его содержимое:

```py
# Импортируем библиотеку с помощью которой будем выполнять запрос
import requests 

# Выполняем запрос с помощью которого мы получим слова и фамилии
first_reply = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/danakt/russian-words/master/russian.txt') 
second_reply = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/danakt/russian-words/master/russian_surnames.txt')
```

Итак, содержимое есть, но тут присутствует одна ма-а-аленькая проблема. Все содержимое закодировано в формат *Windows-1251*. Значит, будем декодировать в привычный для нас формат:

```py
# Декодируем их, так как используется кодировка "windows-1251"
russian_words = first_reply.content.decode('cp1251')
russian_surnames = second_reply.content.decode('cp1251')
```

Декодировали, осталось их в массив запихнуть. У переменных формата **str** есть функция **splitlines**. Она переводит все строки в один список по порядку. А ниже её применение:

```py
# Преобразовываем все строки в один лист
list_words = russian_words.splitlines()
list_surnames = russian_surnames.splitlines()
```

**Готово!** Вот так легко мы получили список русских слов и фамилий. Если будут еще вопросы задавайте их в комментарии.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, очень чёткое и понятное объяснение.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста :)